# Ninject WebAPI.SelfHost Performance Issues under load (for a few seconds every few more seconds)

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api, ninject, self-hosting

I'm throwing some load tests at my WebAPI Self Hosted application and have found that Ninject's Cache Pruning stalls the application for a few seconds (profiling under load in the screenshot).

How can I avoid having the Cache Pruning stall requests??

All I have done is set the HttpSelfHostConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(new StandardKernel())  (configuration omitted)

Is there a way to Remove the Object at the end of the request?

**UPDATE:**

From here, https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/37, it seems that expecting the object to be removed at the end of the request can only be expected for Ninject.Web and Ninject.Web.MVC

**UPDATE/NOTE:**

I've been using the nuget package Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC, along with AttributeRouting.WebApi.Hosted.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I updated the scope and resolver definitions, now I find I have a hang...  I'm now simply testing against an action which returns a string constant.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use https://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi.Selfhost

Here is an example how to use it:
https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/tree/master/src/Ninject.Web.WebApi.Selfhost

It disposes objects InRequestScope at the end of the request.

Comment: thank you - this (https://github.com/remogloor/Ninject.Web.WebApi/tree/master/src/Ninject.Web.WebApi.Selfhost) is where I was just looking actually.  Is that the main motivation for something specific to WebApi, disposing the object?

Comment: Just saw that the hot path is the activation cache. So this probably won't fix that problem. Give me an update how it is going with this version. And no removing objects isn't the main motivation. The main motivation is to have the same way to use Ninject in MVC and WebAPI

Comment: I switched packages, and am following suite of your example self host application.  But I'm currently 'stuck' at an error: Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DefaultServices System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_Services()'.  Still digging though...

Comment: I get the above on constructing the StandardKernel(), any thoughts? Searches point to stale binaries?

Comment: Definitely stuck :(     at Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebApiModule.Load()
   at Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule.OnLoad(IKernel kernel)
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 m)
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
   at Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 filenames)
   at Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 patterns)
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 filePatterns)

Comment: at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules)
   at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules)
   at Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules)
   at .Bootstrapper.Factory.CreateKernel(String assemblies, String plugins)

Comment: Im going to open this as a new question - i cannot get that to build/run

Comment: Sorry to continue a monologue here Remo, but I got it building and almost running.  I had to use the binaries in your lib directory.  May I ask, where do those come from??? I notice the version number on those are higher?  Are they builds of a future WebAPI?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to roll back that integration.  The slightly older binaries which are required in lib (4.0.20505 vs 4.0.20710) do get the self host starting, but it breaks other library integrations.  In particular the attribute based routing which we need to define the routes across separate assemblies.

Comment: Did you ever hear back on this?  I am having same issue and cannot move forward.  Swapped to autofac for now, but hoping to get ninject up soon